# l/sapply ignores conditional replacement

Tags: r, list, loops, replace, lapply

I have a somewhat complex data structure, with a list of lists – which, in turn, each have numeric vectors of different lengths. I need to replace some of the values in the vectors by NAs, based on a separate vector of the same length as the main list. But, rather than replacing only the specific values, R is replacing the whole vector. Bellow, an example:

```
> ## Minimal example with a list of vectors
> # Creating list
> mylist = rep(list(1:3), 3)
> 
> # Vector on which I will base the replacement
> myvec = 1:3
> 
> # Replacing 1s by NA
> for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
+   mylist[[i]] = sapply(mylist[[i]], function(x) x[x ==myvec[i]] = NA)
+ }
> 
> # But I get NAs for every observation
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] NA NA NA

[[2]]
[1] NA NA NA

[[3]]
[1] NA NA NA

> 
> # This is what I wanted:
> list(c(NA, 2, 3), c(1, NA, 3), c(1, 2, NA))
[[1]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[2]]
[1]  1 NA  3

[[3]]
[1]  1  2 NA

> 
> 
> ## More complex example, with a list of lists of vectors that more closely approximates my data structure
> # Creating list of lists
> mynewlist = rep(list(rep(list(1:3), 3)), 3)
> 
> # Replacing 1s by NAs
> for(i in 1:length(mynewlist)){
+   mynewlist[[i]] = lapply(mynewlist[[i]], function(x) x[x ==myvec[i]] = NA)
+ }
> 
> # But now each vector becomes a single NA
> mynewlist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[3]]
[1] NA


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[2]][[3]]
[1] NA


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[3]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]][[3]]
[1] NA


> 
> # What I wanted:
> list(rep(list(c(NA, 2, 3)), 3), rep(list(c(1, NA, 3)), 3), rep(list(c(1, 2, NA)), 3))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] NA  2  3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  1 NA  3

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  1 NA  3

[[2]][[3]]
[1]  1 NA  3


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1]  1  2 NA

[[3]][[2]]
[1]  1  2 NA

[[3]][[3]]
[1]  1  2 NA
```

Notice that the same happens regardless of the specific value of the substitution (if, rather than NA, I change the replacement to 0, for example, then 0 replaces all values, regardless of the condition).

What's going on? Why is lapply/sapply ignoring the condition?

Incidentally, I welcome suggestions to do this without any for loops.

Edit: in addition to editing the code above to make it clear that I'm basing the replacement on a separate vector (hence the for loop), I've been able to get what I want with ifelse. I still don't understand, though, why l/sapply doesn't recognize the selection and replacement with brackets. I'd appreciate any explanation on that, as well as on how to do this without a loop.

Code with ifelse:

```
> # Creating list of lists
> mynewestlist = rep(list(rep(list(1:3), 3)), 3)
> 
> # Replacing 1s by NAs
> for(i in 1:length(mynewestlist)){
+   mynewestlist[[i]] = lapply(mynewestlist[[i]], function(x) ifelse(x ==myvec[i], NA, x))
+ }
> 
> # That's better:
> mynewestlist
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] NA  2  3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  1 NA  3

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  1 NA  3

[[2]][[3]]
[1]  1 NA  3


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1]  1  2 NA

[[3]][[2]]
[1]  1  2 NA

[[3]][[3]]
[1]  1  2 NA


> list(rep(list(c(NA, 2, 3), 3), rep(list(1, NA, 3), 3), rep(list(1, 2, NA), 3))
```

Comment: You need `lapply(mylist, function(x) replace(x, x <=1, NA))`  If you are using `for` loop, you don't need an `sapply` there i.e. `for(i in seq_along(mylist)) mylist[[i]] <- replace(mylist[[i]], mylist[[i]] <=1, NA)`

Comment: ... or using your notation, you have to return x in your l/sapply call ie `mylist = lapply(mylist, function(x) {x[x <= 1] = NA ; x})`

Comment: This makes sense. I guess I need to inform l/ sapply of what to do when the condition is not met? If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, I've edited the original post to explain why I *think* I need a loop; I'm replacing based on a separate vector of the same length as the final list.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia  I posted my comment as a solution.  Hope this explains the problem you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to have `sapply` to run on each element of the `list` element as we can do this in vectorized form.

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) replace(x, x <=1, NA))
```

or with a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(mylist)) mylist[[i]] <- replace(mylist[[i]], 
                          mylist[[i]] <=1, NA)
```

---

Notice that the OP changed the condition, i.e. creating a vector ('myvec') of same length as 'mylist' and want to replace those values that match the corresponding elements of 'mylist' to NA.  It can be done in a lot of ways.  One option is `Map` to loop through the each of the elements of `list` and `vector` and `replace` the value that matches with NA.

```
Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x == y, NA), mylist, myvec)
#[[1]]
#[1] NA  2  3

#[[2]]
#[1]  1 NA  3

#[[3]]
#[1]  1  2 NA
```

or with the `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(mylist)) mylist[[i]] <- replace(mylist[[i]], 
                      mylist[[i]] == myvec[i], NA)
```

Or using `lapply` by looping through the sequence

```
lapply(seq_along(mylist) function(i) 
          replace(mylist[[i]], mylist[[i]] == myvec[i], NA))
```

---

Regarding why the OP is getting only NAs, in the `sapply`, the return value is the assignment to `NA` and is not the object itself.  Check the output of `lapply/sapply` here

```
lapply(mylist[[1]], function(x) x[x==myvec[1]] <- NA)
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] NA
```

It is the assignment value, instead of 'x'.  Return 'x' to get the output of 'x' (as @user20650 commented)

```
lapply(mylist[[1]], function(x) {x[x==myvec[1]] <- NA; x})
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3
```